# This JavaScript function should open a URL in a new Microsoft Edge window. "Internet Explorer mode" in Edge causes it to open in a new tab instead

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an old application written in Java and JavaScript. It's old enough that large portions of it will only work in Internet Explorer (or Microsoft Edge with "Internet Explorer mode" turned on). There's a button in the application that should open a URL in a new Microsoft Edge window, even if the user is accessing the app from Internet Explorer. It has to open in Microsoft Edge for reasons that I was not told. A simplified version of the JavaScript function that is executed onClick is pasted below. I tested this simplified version and the bug still happens with this just like it does with the actual code.

```
function openGoogleWindow(){
    var url = "microsoft-edge:https://google.com";
    window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,left=500,width=600,height=600");               
}
```

The problem is when a user is accessing the application in Microsoft Edge with "Internet Explorer mode" turned on, the URL will open in a new tab in the same window instead of opening a new window altogether. I've tested it in other browsers and in Edge with Internet Explorer mode off. The button opens a new Edge window in all scenarios except when in Edge with Internet Explorer mode on.

One thing I noticed is that a new window will open briefly when the user clicks on the button, but it disappears before the URL's content loads and then opens a new tab in the original window and loads the web page there.

Is there a way to have the button always open a new window in Edge without turning off Internet Explorer mode?

Comment: I tested with your code, actually it always opens in a new tab instead of a new window in Edge. The new window is always opened in a full-size Edge window. If you have a previously opened Edge window, then run the code in other browsers, it will also open the new window in a tab of the previously opened Edge window. The key is `microsoft-edge:` protocol in the url, not IE mode. If you remove `microsoft-edge:` protocol, it will always open in a new window including in Edge IE mode.